# Extend view under status bar on Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, android-statusbar

We've been trying to migrate our codebase to compile (without using deprecations) against API 30 and have ran into some issues with the broad deprecations dealing with the system UI and window insets.

We're trying to have content drawn under a persistent status bar, but not under the nav bar. (so `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` doesn't work)

Previously we were doing this:

```kotlin
activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility?.let {
    activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = it and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
}

binding.start.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
```

I've been able to get the status bar consistently turned light via

```kotlin
window.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
```

Using insets the controller, but I can't figure out how to get the view to extend up under the status bar.

I tried messing with the insets but `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` isn't called anymore for their modifications.

Looking all over the web I don't see any non-deprecated way to get this behavior. I'm wondering if this is even possible anymore?

Comment: So basically you want your activity to draw behind a transparent status bar?

Answer (score 1):

In style

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

In Manifest

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

[image]

In my Android 11, The status bar icon color also changes light and dark while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this resource about Android 11 insets and was able get this working:
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/android11-windowinsets-part1/

The final compat version to get my desired look is this:

```kotlin
        // force view to be full screen and appearance to be light
        //
        activity?.window?.let { window ->
            WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
            window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            val controller = WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, binding.root)
            controller.isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = false
        }
        // Adjust view to be under status bar
        //
        binding.root.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, windowInsets ->
            val insetsCompat = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(windowInsets, view)
            val insets = insetsCompat.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
            binding.root.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                updateMargins(insets.left, insets.top, insets.right, insets.bottom)
            }
            WindowInsetsCompat.Builder()
                .setInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars(), insets)
                .build().toWindowInsets() ?: windowInsets
        }
```

The important bits I learned was that if you setDecorFitsSystemWindows to false then the onApplyWindowInsets *will* be called which allows you to custom inset your view however you'd like.

This is working and giving the same (correct) results from our min of api 26 to 30.